# deploying rails app on ubuntu ec2 with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, syntax-error, capistrano

Several people have asked fairly similar questions to this, so I'm sorry to repeat 'old questions' but I'm completely stuck atm.  I'll try to make it as clear as possible what the problem is:

I have a rails app that works locally.
I am using capistrano to try to deploy it on an ubuntu EC2 instance.

After wading through previous problems, I'm coming up against this when running the
        'cap deploy' command
(I removed the ec2 server name):

```
    executing "cd -- /u/apps/tweet_app/releases/20130628110910 && bundle exec rake        
    RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["ec2 server name"]
    [ec2 server name] executing command
    [out :: ec2 server name] rake aborted!
    [out :: ec2 server name]         
    /u/apps/twitter_app/releases/20130628110910/config/routes.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
     ** [out :: ec2 server name] resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
     ** [out :: ec2 server name] ^
     ** [out :: ec2 server name]         
     /u/apps/tweet_app/releases/20130628110910/config/routes.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
     ** [out :: ec2 server name] resources :annotations, only: [:create]
     ** [out :: ec2 server name] ^
     ** [ec2 server name]     
     etc...
```

Previously, I had an error in my config/initializers/session_store.rb which related to an issue between differences in ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2.  I was able to resolve it by changing the syntax for hashes.  To get to the root of the problem I tried to install ruby 1.9.2 (I also tried 1.9.3) on the ubuntu instance. 1.9.2 is apparently running -

```
    ubuntu@ip-address:~$ ruby --version
    ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
```

But the error still doesn't seem to resolve. It feels like it is still trying to use 1.8.7, which would account for the syntax errors. Other things I have tried include
1. Using rvm to install ruby 1.9.2 on ubuntu (after getting nowhere with a standard install)
2. Using a .rvmrc file to specify that 1.9.2 should be used with the app

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: The problem seems to have been solved by updating everything I could possibly update.  Don't really understand why, but it works :)

Comment: Try to check the rake version with `which rake`